# Further question on previous post "What Does the Forcing Relation Mean Semantically"

Tags: set-theory, forcing

**Now includes edits to the question to correct for the mistake in Equation (3), as identified by vsotvep**

Could I ask a question relating to the last step in the elegant answer to [What does the Forcing relation mean semantically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568459/what-does-the-forcing-relation-mean-semantically?answertab=votes#tab-top) - see summary of the previous posting below between the horizontal lines (with slightly changed notation only and my introduction of Equation (2)), with my question posed afterwards:

---

"In particular, the case $p \Vdash x_0 = x_1$ appears tricky to me. The definition states the following (I am assuming that $M$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC); suppose $x$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name for some forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ if it comprises ordered pairs where the first cooridnate is another $\mathbb{P}$-name, and the second coordinate is a condition. I follows the standard convention that $p \leq q$ means $p$ is stronger than $q$.

> Suppose $\mathbb{P} \in M$ is a forcing notion in some countable transitive model of ZFC. Suppose $p \in \mathbb{P}$ is a condition, and $x_0$ and $x_1$ are $\mathbb{P}$-names. We say $p \Vdash x_0 = x_1$ if the following holds: for any $\langle y,s \rangle \in x_0$ the set $$ \{ q \leq p \mid q \leq s \rightarrow \exists\langle y',s'\rangle \in x_1 (q \leq s' \land  q \Vdash y=y')  \} \tag{1}$$ is dense below $p$, and vice versa with $x_0$ and $x_1$ swapped symmetrically)."

The relevant bits of the answer include :

Suppose $M$ is a c.t.m., $\mathbb{P}\in M$ is a forcing notion, and $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$. We can as usual define the generic extension $M[G]$ - note that this does not involve any appeal to the forcing notion itself, it's simply a direct recursive construction.

The forcing notion $\Vdash_\mathbb{P}$ is then **defined** as follows:

> For $p\in\mathbb{P}$ and $\varphi$ a sentence in the forcing language we write $p\Vdash\varphi$ iff for all $G$ which are $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$ we have $$p\in G\implies M[G]\models\varphi[G]$$

where $\varphi[G]$ is the result of replacing each name occurring in $\varphi$ with its evaluation at $G$)

For example, let's look at the case of equality. We have:

- $p\Vdash x_0= x_1$ iff for all $G\ni p$ generic we have $x_0[G]=x_1[G]$.
- ... which holds iff for each $G\ni p$ generic and $\langle y,s\rangle\in x_0$ then

$$s\in G\implies \exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s'\in G\wedge y[G]=y'[G]),$$ or equivalently :

$$\forall G\ni p [s\in G\implies \exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s'\in G\wedge y[G]=y'[G])]\tag{2}$$

with the "$s\in G\implies$" bit here addressing the fact that if $s\not\in G$ then the pair $\langle y,s\rangle$ doesn't get "triggered" and so we don't care what it does *(and identically with $x_0$ and $x_1$ flipped)*.....

- OK, now let's start to peel away the reference to $G$ in the above, shooting instead for a characterization in terms of individual conditions and dense sets. $p\Vdash x_0=x_1$ is just saying that for every $\langle y,s\rangle\in x_0$ the situation above is **unavoidable by generic filters containing $p$** *(and identically with $x_0$ and $x_1$ flipped)*.
- Specifically, suppose $q\le p$ and $q\le s$ (so $q$ is something that $p$ so far doesn't rule out and also "triggers $y$ in $x_0$"). Then we want there to be some q and some $\langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1$ such that $q\le s'$ (that is, $q$ "triggers $y'$ in $x_1$") and $q\Vdash y=y'$ *(and identically with $x_0$ and $x_1$ flipped)*.

---

**My questions is :**

Why is Equation (2) logically equivalent to Equation (1) - for example it doesn't look like it is because the conversion from Equation (2) to Equation (1) appears to 'roughly' require $\forall G\ni q \exists\langle y',s'\rangle \in x_1 $ to be converted to $ \exists\langle y',s'\rangle \in x_1 \forall G\ni q $ which are not logically equivalent. To elaborate:

Suppose the G are labelled by each of the elements q in $\mathbb{P}$ then with $\boldsymbol{G(q)=\{G:q \in G\}}$ -

$$\{G\} \Leftrightarrow \boldsymbol{\bigcup \{G(q) :  q \in \mathbb{P} \}}$$

The idea being to split all the G into collections having q $\in$ G (i.e. G(q)), for each $q \in \mathbb{P}$ so that a test "for all G" is the same as a "test for all $q \in \mathbb{P}$" and "test for all G in G(q)" . This means as $\forall G \in G(q) \Leftrightarrow \forall G \ni q $ that :

$$\forall G  \    \ \Leftrightarrow \    \ (\forall  q\in \mathbb{P}   \; \forall G \in G(q)) \    \ \Leftrightarrow \    \ (\forall  q\in \mathbb{P} \;  \forall G \ni q) $$

and as by definition $\forall G \ni p(X) \Leftrightarrow \forall G (p \in G \implies X)$ so :

$$\forall G \ni p (X) \    \ \Leftrightarrow \    \ \forall G (p\in G \implies X) \    \ \Leftrightarrow \    \ \forall  q\in \mathbb{P} \;  \forall G \ni q (p\in G \implies X)   \tag{3}$$

Then Equation (2) would be equivalent to, by inserting (3) into (2) :

$$\forall  q\in \mathbb{P} \;  \forall G \ni q (p \in G \implies [s\in G\implies \exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s'\in G\wedge y[G]=y'[G])])\tag{4}$$

To get Equation (4) to look anything like Equation **(1)** would require the $\forall G \ni q$ to be moved into the RHS of the expression (ie 'illegally' through the $\exists$ symbol) :

$$\forall  q\in \mathbb{P} \;  (p \in G \implies [s\in G\implies \exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s'\in G\wedge \boldsymbol{\forall G \ni q (y[G]=y'[G])})])\tag{5}$$

since this would be the same as :

$$\forall  q\in \mathbb{P} \;  (p \in G \implies [s\in G\implies \exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s'\in G\wedge \boldsymbol{q \Vdash y=y')}])\tag{6}$$

To get to this point required an illegal conversion of $\forall \exists$ to $\exists \forall$ (presumably to get $q \leq s'$ etc would require other information to be used, but I got stuck at this point). Indeed suppose Equation (4) does not have a single $\langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1$ for which $q \Vdash y=y'$. However despite this, for example, there may be half of the set {$G \; :\; q\in G$} having $\langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1$ with y[G]=y'[G], but the other half having a different $\langle y'',s''\rangle\in x_1$ with y[G]=y''[G], even though its false that $q \Vdash y=y'$. So some solutions may be missed, or an incorrect solution produced?

Any help in sorting out what I have missed will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Is $\forall G\ni p(\dots)$ a shorthand for $\forall G(p\in G\to \dots)$? If so, your equation (3) doesn't make sense syntactically, and from there on I'm a bit lost at what you're trying to do... If you don't mean this shorthand, what does $\forall G\ni p$ mean?

Comment: Hi Vsotvep, I edited the question to address your point. Thanks

Comment: I have written an answer trying to summarise how the two forcing relations are equivalent. I still am not completely certain if I understand your question correctly, so let me know if my answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually like to mark all $\Bbb P$-names with a dot ($\dot x$) to keep it clear that these are names, and I like to write the interpretation of a name $\dot x$ by some generic $G$ as $\dot x_G$.

Now, your question mentions two definitions of the forcing relation $\Vdash$:

- the **outside definition** states if $\mathcal M$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with $p\in\Bbb P\in\mathcal M$, then $\mathcal M\vDash (p\Vdash_O \phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n))$ if and only if $\mathcal M[G]\vDash \phi(\dot x^1_G,\dots,\dot x^n_G)$ for all $G\subseteq \Bbb P$ that are $\Bbb P$-generic over $\mathcal M$ and have $p\in G$.
- the **inside definition** is recursive over the complexity of the formula $\phi$ and the [von Neumann rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) of the names $\dot x^1,\dots, \dot x^n$. For instance, if $\phi\equiv \dot x=\dot x'$, then $p\Vdash_I \dot x=\dot x'$ if and only if for every $(\dot y,s)\in \dot x$ the set $$D=\{q\leq p\mid q\leq s\to \exists(\dot y',s')\in \dot x'(q\leq s'\text{ and }q\Vdash_I \dot y=\dot y')\}$$
  is dense below $p$, and vice versa with the roles of $\dot x$ and $\dot x'$ swapped. There are similar definitions for $\phi$ being $\dot x\in \dot x'$, $\psi\land \chi$ or $\exists x\psi$ based on dense sets which I will not state here, but for later let us give the definition for $\lnot\psi$: we have $p\Vdash_I\lnot \psi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$ if and only if $q\not\Vdash_I \psi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)\}$ for all $q\leq p$.

I believe your question asks why $\Vdash_O$ and $\Vdash_I$ are equivalent. The main theorem we need, is the following:

> **Forcing Theorem** (also known as the Truth Lemma)
> Let $G\subseteq\Bbb P$ be a generic filter, $\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ a formula and $\dot x^1,\dots\dot x^n$ be $\Bbb P$-names. Then $\mathcal M[G]\vDash \phi(\dot x^1_G,\dots,\dot x^n_G)$ if and only if there exists $p\in G$ such that $p\Vdash_I\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$.

Note that this theorem only talks about a certain fixed $G$, and does not quantify over *all* generic filters $G$, so we have not yet reached the outside definition of the forcing relation. However, to prove the Forcing Theorem, you will not need to quantify over the generic filters. Unless I'm mistaken, this should solve your problem of "illegal conversion from $\forall\exists$ to $\exists\forall$".

The proof of the Forcing Theorem is mostly technical, but it is important to note that it is proved by induction in the same way that the inside definition is defined by recursion. In particular, one assumes that the theorem has been proved for all formulas $\psi$ of lower complexity than $\phi$ and all names $\dot y$ with rank strictly below $\max\{\mathrm{rk}(\dot x^k)\mid 1\leq k\leq n\}$. The base case of the induction with regard to the complexity of $\phi$ occur when we consider the atomic formulas $\dot x=\dot x'$ and $\dot x\in \dot x'$, and in turn the base case with regard to the rank of the names occurs when each name is the empty name.

For more details, I recommend to take a look in the literature. In particular Kunen's *Set Theory* is a standard reference, but there are many other books that go through the details (e.g. Schindler's *Set Theory*, Halbeisen's *Combinatorial Set Theory*)

---

We can use the Forcing Theorem to prove that $p\Vdash_O\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$ is equivalent to $p\Vdash_I\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$, assuming that we know that the model $\mathcal M\vDash\mathsf{ZFC}$ exists (in fact, for practical purposes we only need a large enough finite fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, which solves problems regarding Gödel's incompleteness, see also Kunen's book), $\Bbb P\in \mathcal M$ and that for every $p\in \Bbb P$ there exists some filter $G\subset \Bbb P$ (outside of $\mathcal M$) that contains $p$ and that intersects all dense subsets of $\Bbb P$ contained in $\mathcal M$. These assumptions are necessary for the outside definition to be made at all, and hence we are working in universe $\bf V\ni\mathcal M$ that is large enough to contain sufficiently many $G$ that are $\Bbb P$-generic over $\mathcal M$.

---

*Proof.*

($\Vdash_I$ implies $\Vdash_O$)
If $p\Vdash_I\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$ and $p\in G$, then the Forcing Theorem tells us that $\mathcal M[G]\vDash \phi(\dot x^1_G,\dots,\dot x^n_G)$. This holds for any $G$ with $p\in G$, so it follows that $p\Vdash_O\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$.

($\Vdash_O$ implies $\Vdash_I$)
If $p\Vdash_O\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$, let's assume that $p\not\Vdash_I\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$. Then the set of conditions $\{q\leq p\mid q\Vdash_I\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)\}$ is **not dense** below $p$, so we can fix some $q\leq p$ for which $r\not\Vdash_I\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$ for all $r\leq q$. But then $q\Vdash_I\lnot \phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$. As we've already seen above, this implies $q\Vdash_O\lnot \phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$. Now let $G$ be a generic filter with $q\in G$, then also $p\in G$ since $q\leq p$. But, using the definition of $\Vdash_O$, we now see that:

- $q\Vdash_O\lnot \phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$ implies $\mathcal M[G]\vDash\lnot \phi(\dot x^1_G,\dots,\dot x^n_G)$, while
- $p\Vdash_O\phi(\dot x^1,\dots,\dot x^n)$ implies $\mathcal M[G]\vDash\phi(\dot x^1_G,\dots,\dot x^n_G)$

Hence we have reached a contradiction.

Comment: Vsotvep : thanks, nice summary & simple proof steps. I'm thinking on your response. One initial question though : In (⊩I implies ⊩O), why does the Forcing Theorem show "This holds for any G with p∈G" ? Cant the value p vary with G, due to the "There exists a p in G" part of the Forcing Theorem ? So just because for a given G that p⊩Iϕ(x˙1,…,x˙n) doesn't mean that a different G could have p, but but not have p⊩Iϕ(x˙1,…,x˙n) - but could have a q instead that gives q⊩Iϕ(x˙1,…,x˙n) ? [Also apologies - I don't know how to put formulae in comments]

Comment: @LittleCheese What one wants to prove in ($\Vdash_I$ implies $\Vdash_O$), is that for a fixed $p$, if it forces a formula with the inside definition, then it forces it with the outside definition. So, we can take an arbitrary $G$ containing $p$, then the forcing theorem tells us that the formula is valid in $\mathcal M[G]$. Since $G$ was arbitrary, this holds for all $G$ that contain $p$. This is exactly the definition of $\Vdash_O$. Of course there could exist $G'$ with $q\in G'$ such that $q$ forces the same formula, but this is irrelevant since we only care about $p$, right?

Comment: Also, you ask "doesn't mean that a different $G$ could have $p$, but not have $p\Vdash_I\phi$". This is impossible: the definition of $\Vdash_I$ does not depend on anything but the formula, the names and $p$ itself (note that all of these are defined in the ground model $\mathcal M$). The generic $G$ isn't mentioned in the definition (and shouldn't be, since $G$ is undefined in the ground model). When $p$ forces something and $p\in G$, then $p$ forces it when $p\in G'$. The point is that $p$ forces something, the generic has no influence over that.

Comment: Vsotvep : As you suggested I have read the Kunen proof of the Truth Lemma (Page 198 of 10th impression - pdf available on the internet). I have rephrased my question to relate it to the proof of (2) at the top of Page 198 i.e. $\forall G$ ($\phi[G]$ $\implies$ $\exists p \in G (p \Vdash \phi $)). The proof of Kunen (1) is not affected by this comment. 

The definition of $p\Vdash$ for equality is, with G generic :

$$ p\Vdash x_0= x_1 \Leftrightarrow \forall G\ni p \;\;x_0[G]=x_1[G] \tag{a}  $$

Comment: ... which holds iff for each $G\ni p$ generic and $\langle y,s\rangle\in x_0$ and $s \in G$ then

$$ 
\exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s'\in G\wedge y[G]=y'[G]),$$ or equivalently assuming $p \in G$ and $s \in G$ and $G$ generic :

$$\forall G [\exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s'\in G\wedge y[G]=y'[G])]\tag{b}$$

As $\forall x \exists y X$ $\Leftrightarrow$ (($\exists y \forall x X) \lor W)$, where W includes other possible solutions, equation (b) is logically equivalent to :

Comment: $$ \exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s' \Vdash y=y') \; \lor \; Z  \tag{c}  $$

This could mean that there could be other solutions to (a) in addition to those just involving the use of the internal definition of $\Vdash$, because the negation of the internal definition of $\Vdash$ may not be the same as the negation of the rhs of (a), using (c):

$$ \neg (\forall G\ni p \;\;x_0[G]=x_1[G]) \leftrightarrow  \neg (\exists \langle y',s'\rangle\in x_1 (s' \Vdash y=y')) \; \land \; \neg Z$$

Comment: In the Kunen proof of (2) $\forall G$ ($\phi[G]$ $\implies$ $\exists p \in G (p \Vdash \phi $)) a set D is created with what looks to be essentially:

 $$ D := \{ r \; | \; (r \Vdash x_1 = x_2) \; \lor \; [\neg (r \Vdash x_1 = x_2) \Rightarrow \alpha'] \} = \{ r \; | \; (r \Vdash x_1 = x_2) \; \lor \; \alpha' \}$$

and showing no r $\in G$ can make $\alpha'$ true, so as D is dense there must be a $p \in G$ with $(p \Vdash x_1 = x_2 $).

Comment: However, what has happened to the Z terms? Is it possible that M would not know about these other solutions and only 'thinks' that given $\phi[G]$ there must always be a $p \in G$ with $(p \Vdash x_1 = x_2 $)?

Comment: @LittleCheese I will not have time to answer this week, so if you want a quicker response it may be better to ask this in a separate question. If the question stays unanswered until after the weekend I'll see if I can give an answer later.

Comment: no rush, I'm trying to delve a little deeper into why p⊩Oϕ(x˙1,…,x˙n) is equivalent to p⊩Iϕ(x˙1,…,x˙n), as I'm looking to use aspects of Forcing in Physics and so how the definition of ⊩I is derived. If you manage to find some time to consider the comment it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Vsotvep - using your answer I have seen the light - there is no "illegal conversion of ∀∃ to ∃∀" needed to define $\Vdash$.